# xxhash function is trying to add more than uint32 max?

Tags: c

I don't understand how [this xxhash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/master/xxhash.c) function is able to add larger values than uint32 can store. Can someone explain why this wizardry is possible?

```
    static const U32 PRIME32_1 = 2654435761U;
    static const U32 PRIME32_2 = 2246822519U;
    ...
    U32 v1 = seed + PRIME32_1 + PRIME32_2;
```

Comment: I'm gonna say that's no different than `v1=seed+606290984;` and I suspect that it's supposed to be `v1=seed * PRIME32_1 + PRIME32_2;` since that's the proper way to make a [linear congruential random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard requires that the standard unsigned integral types handle overflow/underflow by 'wrapping' the value modulo `FOO_MAX + 1`. (e.g. `UINT32_MAX` is the macro holding the maximum value of `uint32_t`)

Assuming `U32` refers to `uint32_t`, the additions are performed modulo `4294967296`.